# Trouble installing pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, installation, centos

I'm trying to install the pgrouting library but have hit a bit of a problem whilst installing. It's probably something I've done (I'm quite new to Linux so struggling to understand the error message). Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas of how to resolve it?

```
[root@localhost pgrouting]# git clone git://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting.git pgrouting

[root@localhost pgrouting]# cd pgrouting

[root@localhost pgrouting]# sudo /root/cmake-2.8.3-Linux-i386/bin/cmake .

[root@localhost pgrouting]# make install

[ 16%] Building CXX object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.o /root/pgrouting/core/src/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.cpp:26:54: error: boost/property_map/vector_property_map.hpp: No such file or directory In file included from /root/pgrouting/core/src/shooting_star_search.hpp:22, from /root/pgrouting/core/src/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.cpp:27: /root/pgrouting/core/src/shooting_star_relax.hpp:18:47: error: boost/property_map/property_map.hpp: No such file or directory make[2]: [core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.o] Error 1 make[1]:[core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/all] Error 2 make: [all] Error 2
```

I followed the instructions given at http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install_centos.html and I'm installing on CentOS 5.5.

Comment: Also try submitting this to the mailing list. the response time on it is usually very fast

Comment: Great idea, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way to get up and running is to simply install the [OSGeo Live DVD](http://live.osgeo.org/), which already has pgRouting pre-installed and configured.  I set it up as a virtual machine using either [VMWare Player](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_player/3_0) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), both free to use.

Comment: Oh wow, wish I had known about this before, spent the last 5 days failing to get everything up and running! I'll download this now and give it a shot.

Answer (score 5):

Hallo

It looks like you need Boost libraries. Probably you have not installed boost dev files.

HTH

Nicklas

Comment: Hi Nicklas, I actually had both Boost and Boost-devel installed.. however it wasn't the latest version and it wasn't available via yum. I tried compiling it manually but it still picked up the old version even though that was uninstalled. I've given up and am gonna try OSGeo!